# How to pass the DataValueField of a DDL as an Int32 to a FormView Update SQL statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, formview

The following code is causing an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type Int to String.

The problem lies here: `Convert.ToInt32(priorityLanguage_DDL.DataValueField);` I wonder why!

```
protected void UpdateButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   

    DropDownList priorityLanguage_DDL = FormView3.FindControl("priorityLanguage_DDL") as DropDownList;
    SqlDataSource_membersDetails.UpdateParameters["priorityLanguage_ddl_par"].Type = TypeCode.Int32;
    SqlDataSource_membersDetails.UpdateParameters["priorityLanguage_ddl_par"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToInt32(priorityLanguage_DDL.DataValueField);

}
```

UPDATE

The correct answer is to replace priorityLanguage_DDL.DataValueField with priorityLanguage_DDL.SelectedValue....

Comment: As I can see, you're passing a field name as a parameter's DefaultValue. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Because [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property is a `string` and you are trying assing an `int`.

Comment: So how can I pass an Int value to the SQL Update statement? Thank you

Comment: remove the Convert.ToInt32

Comment: I removed the Convert.ToInt32. Now I get another error: Input string was not in a correct format.  SqlDataSource_membersDetails.UpdateParameters["priorityLanguage_ddl_par"].DefaultValue = priorityLanguage_DDL.DataValueField;

Comment: I wonder if there is an easy way to send a DataValueField of a DDL nested inside a FormView to its Update SQL Statement....There must be a straightforward code that I don't know of....